# Unable to Seed Data for Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, seed

When I run `rake db:seed` in my Rails 3 application I get the error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method 'find_or_create_by_first_name_and_last_name_and_role_and_email_and_password_and_password_confirmation'
```

Below are my `create_users.rb` and `seeds.rb` files respectively. Why isn't the `find_or_create_by_*` method being dynamically created?

```
def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name, :null => false
      t.string :last_name, :null => false
      t.string :role, :null => false
      t.string :email, :null => false
      t.string :crypted_password, :null => false
      t.string :password_salt, :null => false
      t.string :persistence_token, :null => false
      t.string :current_login_ip
      t.string :last_login_ip
      t.datetime :current_login_at
      t.datetime :last_login_at

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

`User.find_or_create_by_first_name_and_last_name_and_role_and_email_and_password_and_password_confirmation(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html):

> This dynamic finder is called with find_or_create_by_ and will return the object if it already exists and otherwise creates it, then returns it. **Protected attributes won’t be set unless they are given in a block.** (emphasis mine)

I'm guessing `password` and `password_confirmation` are protected attributes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the constraints when dealing with protected attributes. Changing to `User.create(...)` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "and" between role and email

User.find_or_create_by_first_name_and_last_name_and_role_and_email_and_password_and_password_confirmation(...)

Comment: Sorry, the missing "and" was a typo in my post. It is correctly written in my seeds.rb file and yet the error is present.